# flutter, provider and data tables

Tags: flutter, provider

I'm looking for a way to create a data table with flutter driven by the provider package. But whatever I try with Table() or DataTable() I can't make it happen to connect to a ChangeNotificationProvider.

Both TableRow and DataRaw are not widgets I can connect to the provider. 
I want to achieve a way to the each object from my business model connected to a row in the table.

When a value is changing I don't want to rebuild the whole table (that I could achieve with DateTable). I want to update only the relevant cells and keep the scroll position.

Any hint ? All the samples I could find or build are not really useful for reality.

Comment: Just throwing an idea, Could you try building an array of change notifier each representing a cell? I don't know how much data are you trying to fit in here.

Comment: The amount of data would be manageable I think. Maybe max 100 lines with 10 to 20 columns. ~2000 cells. give or take.

Comment: @ChristianVirtual, did you manage to get that working? could you share your results?